# How can I use Power Automate to rename an attachment using the entered Title on SharePoint Lists

Tags: power-automate

I am looking to automate the renaming of an attachment using the Title entered when the attachment is uploaded to SharePoint lists, i.e. have the user designate the name/title of their attachment.

Thus far I can add a date stamp in Add Attachment, File name.  But this uses the current file name. concat(formatDateTime(addHours(utcNow(), -8),'MMM-dd'), items('Apply_to_each')?['DisplayName']).

Would appreciate any suggestions on how to apply the SharePoint List Title in the renaming or add file command.

Thanks!

[image: Screenshot1]

[image: Screenshot2]
[image: Screenshot3]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your current flow setup. How are you triggering your flow, whenever a new list item is created?

Comment: Yes the trigger is 'When an item is created' then 'Get attachments' then apply to each: get attachment content. I have added screenshots of the 'get attachment content' and 'Add attachment' commands. Trying to add an attachment using the name of the SharePoint list (for ex: as seen in last attachment)

Answer (score 0):

Try an expression like below to use the title of the list item from the trigger action:
concat(formatDateTime(addHours(utcNow(), -8),'MMM-dd'), triggeroutputs()?['Title'])

Comment: Yes I tried that exactly and it returns an attachment with no content and just a date stamp, no Title. Seems I also need a way the added attachment retains the file extension as it does when I use ['DisplayName']).

Comment: update:  I have successfully added attachment using File Name [Title].zip but when I create file I am unsure what to out in File Content. If I put "attachment content" that refers to "get attachment content" and not "added attachment". Ideas on how to refer to the attachment content of the added attachment? also how can I make the extension dynamic instead of indicating .zip?

Comment: With the Get Attachment Content action you are retrieving the attachment and its file content which was added to the list? So, I would say Attachment content from the Get Attachment Content would be ok to use.